# How to make VSCode show me strictNullChecks Typescript errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I build my project with the following `tsconfig.json`, I get an error due to recently adding `strictNullChecks: true`.

```
{
    "version": "2.3.4",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "scripthost"
        ],
        "outDir": "../build/"
    },
    "include": [
        "./*.ts",
        "./*.tsx",
        "./{client,mobile,server,shared,test,tools}/*.ts",
        "./{client,mobile,server,shared,test,tools}/*.tsx",
        "./{client,mobile,server,shared,test,tools}/**/*.ts",
        "./{client,mobile,server,shared,test,tools}/**/*.tsx",
        "./desktop/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

However, I don't see any errors in VSCode.

I also have the following vscode setting:

```
"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib",
```

Everything seems to work fine in VSCode  **except** strictNullChecks errors.

Comment: In a ts file where you expect strict null errors, what happens if you run the `typescript: Go to project configuration` command in vscode? Also, what typescript version is shown in the status bar in the lower right corner?

Comment: Ahhh. Interesting... "File is not part of a TypeScript project"

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not finding it though....

Comment: When I click "Configure tsconfig.json", it opens up my tsconfig.

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work when I get rid of the `include` field...

Comment: What is the path of the file you are in? You likly need to use globs like `./**/*.ts` instead

Comment: Hmm. The problem with that glob is there's a `desktop/node_modules` for building electron apps so I cant match those... Although I suppose thats what exclude is for!

Comment: That was it! Thanks @matt

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file is not excluded by the `include` or `exclude` rules in your `tsconfig.json`.

Likely scenarios include:

- Not including nested folders (e.g. using `*.ts`, `./*.ts`, or other variants, instead of `**/*.ts`). This appears to have been the issue in the original question.
- A newly added `include` rule when none was previously present - specifying any value here will override the default value of `**/*.*`.

Credit to Matt Bierner for tips in the comment on the question. However, it wasn't posted as an answer and so doesn't have proper visibility or prominence.