# Prevent VSCode from collapsing Observable<boolean | undefined> to Observable<boolean>

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've noticed for a while that VSCode likes to collapse a return type of `Observable<boolean | undefined>` to `Observable<boolean>`, and this makes it difficult to see what the 'real' return type of something is by just hovering the mouse over it.

I updated a package today where the return type of a method was changed from `Observable<boolean>` to `Observable<boolean | undefined>`. This had a huge ripple through effect on my codebase, and since I cannot see the actual return type I have to rely on the compiler.

For example if I have this code (animals are more fun than booleans):

```
getAnimal() 
{
    return timer(1000, 1000).pipe(map(timer => (timer % 0 == 0) ? <const>'cat' : <const>'dog'));
}
```

When I hover over the method it shows `Observable<"cat" | "dog">`

[image]

But if I change it to this:

```
getAnimal() 
{
    return timer(1000, 1000).pipe(map(timer => (timer % 0 == 0) ? <const>'cat' : undefined));
}
```

Then it 'collapses' the `undefined` into the type.

[image]

How can I get VSCode to show `Observable<'cat' | undefined>` or `Observable<boolean | undefined>`

I am using typescript 3.9.5. and strict null checks.

Comment: Are you sure that `timer % 0` is correct? Because anything mod 0 is NaN.

Comment: Sorry I spaced out and that was meant to be 2

Answer (score 0):

Well that was dumb. I guess I must have too many .json config files.

I didn't even have this enabled in the one that it was using:

```
 "strictNullChecks": true,
```

If in doubt run the command `Typescript: Go to project configuration` and you'll see the `tsconfig.json` file that's being used.

See also [How to make VSCode show me strictNullChecks Typescript errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854084/how-to-make-vscode-show-me-strictnullchecks-typescript-errors)